# How many playable characters are there in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: pc, steam, super-meat-boy

How many characters are playable in Super Meat Boy PC Steam version and how to unlock them?

Comment: This youtube video might be relevant to the first part of your question: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYiyWsh17W0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 19 for Steam on Windows/Mac OS (15(?) for XBox Live Arcade, different exclusives).

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Meat_Boy) has a list of which characters are available on which platforms, and their origin.

To quote:

> These characters can be unlocked by collecting enough bandages or completing certain warp zones.

There is a fairly solid list of how to get pretty much everything [here](http://www.diygamer.com/2010/10/super-meat-boy-bandage-warp-zone-guide/).

**Summarised:**

```
Character               Origin                 # Bandages
---------------------------------------------------------
Head Crab               Half-Life                      10
Josef (Robot)           Machinarium                    30
8Bit Meat Boy                                          40
Naiji                   Aquaria                        50
4Bit Meat Boy                                          60
RunMan                  RunMan Race Around the World   70
4Color Meat Boy                                        80
Captain Veridian        VVVVVV                         90
Steve (Mr. Minecraft)   Minecraft                     100

Character         Origin            Warp Zone
---------------------------------------------
Commander Video   BIT.TRIP RUNNER        1-12
Jill              Mighty Jill-Off        2-8
Ogmo              Jumper                 3-16
Flywrench         Flywrench              4-18
The Kid           I Want to be the Guy   5-7

Character      Available
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bandage Girl   Once you beat the main game, only in The Cotton Alley world
Meat Ninja     Once you 100% the game

Character        Character Select code   Activate by selecting
--------------------------------------------------------------
Super Tofu Boy   petaphile               Meat Boy
Goo Ball         ballgoo                 ???
Brownie          RB,RB,RB,B,B,B,X        Meat Boy
```

To unlock on the Character Select screen, just type in the listed code on the selection screen which appears when choosing a stage.

[Super Tofu Boy was put in following the PETA incident.](http://supermeatboy.com/65/Super_Meat_Boy_vs_Peta_/)

[According to this](http://www.actiontrip.com/cheats/supermeatboy.phtml), activating Brownie on the Character Select screen requires an XBox 360 controller.

*Teh Internets Chapter* is also unlocked by collecting bandages (20x) and is an online chapter which contains bonus levels.

Comment: A recent patch also added the Goo Ball to Steam versions as a secret character: "World of Goo ball now playable, type ballgoo at the character selection screen". This is the character selection screen that appears when you first select a stage, not the mid-level character switch option.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will edit that in. Going to assume the same logic holds for Tofu Boy, in that you have to type when selecting a stage, not on the mid-level switch?

Comment: 19 characters wow, it will take time to unlock them all

Comment: It seems Tim from Braid is coming to PC/Steam as well: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2238831

Comment: Alien Homonid is also on PC/Steam.  I just unlocked him at the same time that Josef unlocks.  There is no slot for him on the character-select screen in the pause menu - he can only be selected before a level.